# Muliple clients sending UDP data to python socket are getting lost

Tags: python, sockets, udp, buffer

I have a python socket reader to listen for incoming UDP packets from about 5000 clients every minute.  As I started rolling it out it was working fine but now that I'm up to about 4000 clients I'm losing about 50% of the data coming in.  The VM has plenty of memory and CPU so I assume it's something with my UDP socket listener on the server getting too much data at once. Via cron, every minute the clients send in this data:

```
site8385','10.255.255.255','1525215422','3.3.0-2','Jackel','00:15:65:20:39:10'
```

This is the socket reader portion of my listener script.

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
port = 18000
s.bind(('', port))

while True:
   # Establish connection with client.

   d = s.recvfrom(1024)
```

Could it be the buffer size is too small?  How do I determine the size of the packets coming in so I can adjust the 1024 value?

Comment: You should *already* know the size of the datagrams coming in, from your application protocol definition. The usual trick is to use a buffer one byte larger than the maximum, so if you ever get a datagram that size you know it is a protocol error and may also have been truncated.

Comment: Is that 5000/minute around 83/second +/- a few hundred % or so, or is it a storm of almost all 5000 coming at once and then nothing for 59 seconds?

Comment: @abarnert Yes.  They all come at once then nothing for 59 seconds.  Bytes is about 80 per client.

Comment: The number of bytes shouldn't be an issue (unless you're on a 10Mbps pipe, which you probably aren't). But the number of packets per second could be. How much work are you doing after that `d.recvfrom`?

Comment: @abarnert Quite a bit.  Each entry gets written to a mariadb database.

Comment: OK, there are two ways to attack this: (1) try raising your receive buffer size so it doesn't start dropping packets until you get a lot farther behind, or (2) try to service the buffer as fast as possible by just pushing all the messages onto some other pipe (say, a `multiprocessing.Queue` that's serviced by a `multiprocessing.Process`—or, maybe simpler, just throw tasks at a `multiprocessing.Pool` or `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`).

Comment: @abarnert  Increased the buffer to 64K but it's processing about the same as when it was set to 80K.  I also commented out the sql writes but it had no affect either.

Comment: I'm not sure which buffer you increased—but it's not going to make things process any faster; it'll just mean the kernel gives you more time before dropping packets (assuming it's happening in your kernel rather than your NIC, your router, your upstream provider, etc.).

Comment: Meanwhile, if you comment out _all_ the work, not just the SQL writes, does it make any difference?

Comment: @abarnert  Commenting out all the work help immensely and pretty much got all of them.  When I say I changed the buffer size I'm referring to this line: d = s.recvfrom(1024)

Comment: Oh, _that_ buffer size makes no difference at all. You're always going to receive a single message, and if those are usually about 80 bytes, it doesn't matter how much higher than 80 you set the maximum. I meant using `setsockopt` to raise the socket's receive buffer, and possibly using `sysctl` to raise the maximum socket receive buffer so you can raise that even higher. Look up `SO_RCVBUF` on your platform for details (it should be in `man 7 socket`), and a few other sockopts, and the `sysctl` or `/proc` filesystem values mentioned there. (Or, I'll bet there's a good ServerFault question.)

Comment: @abarnert So it's definitely the sql writes that are slowing it down.  Let me purse the options you've provided.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Every 60 seconds, you get a storm of ~5000 messages. You process them sequentially, and it takes "quite a bit" of time. So pretty quickly, one of your buffers gets full up and either your OS, your network card, or your router starts dropping packets. (Most likely it's the buffer your kernel sets aside for this particular socket, and the kernel is dropping the packets, but all of the other options are possible too.)

You could try increasing those buffers. That will give yourself a lot more "allowed lag time", so you can get farther behind before the kernel starts dropping packets. If you want to go down this road, the first step is `setsockopt` to raise the `SO_RCVBUF` value, but you really need to learn about all the issues that could be involved here.<sup>1</sup>

If you control the client code, you could also have the clients stagger their packets (e.g., just sleeping for `random.random() * 55` before the `send`).

But it's probably better to try to actually service those packets as quickly as possible, and do the processing in the background.<sub>2</sub>

Trying to do this in-thread could be ideal, but it could also be very fiddly to get right. A simpler solution is to just a background thread, or a pool of them:

```
def process_msg(d):
    # your actual processing code

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=12) as x:
    while True:
        d = s.recvfrom(1024)
        x.submit(process_msg, d)
```

This *may* not actually help. If your processing is CPU-bound rather than I/O-bound, the background threads will just be fighting over the GIL with the main thread. If you're using Python 2.7 or 3.2 or something else old, even I/O-bound threads can interfere in some situations. But either way, there's an easy fix: Just change that `ThreadPoolExecutor` to a `ProcessPoolExecutor` (and maybe drop `max_workers` to 1 fewer than the number of cores you have, to make sure the receiving code can have a whole core to itself).

---

<sub>1.  Redhat has a nice doc on [Network Performance Tuning](https://access.redhat.com/sites/default/files/attachments/20150325_network_performance_tuning.pdf). It's written more from the sysadmin's point of view than the programmer's, and it expects you to either know, or know how to look up, a lot of background information—but it should be helpful if you're willing to do that. You may also want to try searching Server Fault rather than Stack Overflow if you want to go down this road.</sub>

<sub>2. Of course if there's more than a minute's work to be done to process each minute's messages, the queue will just get longer and longer, and eventually everything will fail catastrophically, which is worse than just dropping some packets until you catch up… But hopefully that's not an issue here.</sub>